# Rapid decay of family of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\{f_y\}_{y\in\mathbb{R}^d} \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a family of functions that depends smoothly on a parameter $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Assume that $\{f_y\}_{y\in\mathbb{R}^d}$ and its derivatives in $y$ decay rapidly in $y$ in the $L^2$-norm, that is, for every multi-index $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^d$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$, a constant $C_{\alpha,N}$ exists such that
$$\| \partial_y^\alpha f_y \|_{L^2} \leq C_{\alpha,N} (1+|y|)^{-N}.$$
Moreover, assume that, for every $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$, the function $x \mapsto f_y(x)$ is differentiable in $x$ (in the classical or weak sense), and $\partial_x f_y \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

**Question**: Does $\partial_x f_y$ decay rapidly in $y$ in the $L^2$-norm as well?

Initially, I started with the weaker assumption $\| f_y \|_{L^2} \leq C_N (1+|y|)^{-N}$ (i.e. not assuming rapid decay of the derivatives in $y$). However, in this case I found a counterexample. If $d=1$, the function
$$f_y(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \mathrm{e}^{-y} \sin(\mathrm{e}^{2y}x)$$
decays rapidly in $y$, but its derivative grows exponentially in $y$. The problem with this counterexample is that $f_y$ oscillates rapidly and the oscillations become stronger when $y$ increases. The above example is excluded when we also assume the derivatives of $\{f_y\}_{y\in\mathbb{R}^d}$ to be rapidly decreasing.

Comment: What about $f_y(x)=e^{-y^2}\sin(e^x)/(1+x^2)$?

Comment: Interesting example, but actually I assume $\partial_x f_y \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ which I haven't mentioned explicitly in my question. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this will work: instead of PhoemueX's $e^{-y^2} \sin e^x/(1+x^2)$, we can use the variant

$$ f_y(x)= e^{-y^2} \chi(x-y^2) \sin e^x$$
where $\chi$ is some cutoff function which is 1 near the origin. This smooth function and all its $y,x$ derivatives trivially belong to all $L^p_x$ spaces by compactness of support. $\|\partial^\alpha_y f_y\|_{L^2_x}$ satisfies all the same estimates up to things like $y^K\chi^{(M)}(x-y^2)$ which can go into the $C_{\alpha,N}$ constant. For the $x$ derivative, while the first term in $$\partial_x f_y(x) = e^{-y^2}  \chi'(x-y^2) \sin e^x + e^{x-y^2}\chi(x-y^2) \cos e^x $$
decays, the second term has $L^2_x$ norm that is $O(1)$ in $y$: $e^{x-y^2}\sim1$, $\chi(x-y^2)\sim 1$, and $\lvert\cos e^x\rvert^2$ presumably has integral strictly bounded away from $0$ on any interval $[a,a+1]$, uniformly in $a$.

Comment: For the last bit: only $x\to\infty$ is of interest. Then  $$\int_a^{a+1} \cos^2 e^x dx = \frac12 + \frac12 \int_{e^a}^{e^{a+1}} \frac{\cos 2y}y dy $$ and the integral term is zero in the limit because the improper Riemann integral of $\frac{\cos 2y}y$ on $[1,\infty)$ is finite